# Samsung devices not opening app from browser url scheme in android

Tags: android

I want to open my app from browser using URL scheme its working fine non Samsung devices but not in Samsung .below is the entry in manifest file

```
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.epub"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to be a [problem  with certain Samsung devices](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/samsung-tab-3-80---opening-the-application-from-browser-does-not-work/202/251278?boardName=General&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=3).

If acceptable for you, custom schemes seem to work.