# Custom url schemes not opening through default Samsung browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

I have an url like this myapp://select?param1=_4O0MSbkzwSzKe_Wcqmm2kSfgmxozRMA2U5dqhPkrfY&param2=cc5646c4e12341020012fc0

Navigating into the url opens my app.
But the same does not work on chrome and Samsung default browser and it opens the search screen
It works fine on firefox and opera.

I checked links [Samsung devices not opening app from browser url scheme in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239133/samsung-devices-not-opening-app-from-browser-url-scheme-in-android).

But opening with javascript:windows.location='myurl' also does not work. (This works on Chrome but).

There is an already fixed bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186 on chromium.

Thanks and Regrards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

You can try `'intent://view?xxx=123#Intent;package=com.example.myapp;scheme=myapp;launchFlags=abc;end;'` when normal `'myapp://xx?'` way did not work after a short time delay.
Test to trigger via window.location or link custom event, or iframe's src one by one. At least one is suitable for your browser. 
lol